# Rails Haml: link_to glyphicon List Item - illegal nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have glyphicons set up like below:

```
 = link_to edit_user_registration_path(pin.user_id), class: "btn btn-default"  do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog
```

However when I put it in a %li I get an illegal nesting error:

```
%ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.custom
   %li= link_to edit_user_registration_path(pin.user_id), class: "btn btn-default" do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog
```

I get the following:

```
Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %li and nested within it.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `link_to` method in the next line:

```
%ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.custom
  %li
    = link_to edit_user_registration_path(pin.user_id), class: "btn btn-default" do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog
```

Which generates:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right custom">
  <li>
    <%= link_to edit_user_registration_path(pin.user_id), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can test it with [haml2erb.org](https://haml2erb.org/).